# Setting up Google App Engine SDK - Doesn't Run App

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After setting up the Python Google App Engine SDK per Google's instructions, I run the sample guestbook application in the launcher and get the following in the log:

```
2011-02-05 18:32:23 Running command: "[u'C:\\Python25\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program    Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--   port=8080', u'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\demos\\guestbook']"
WARNING  2011-02-06 00:32:24,798 datastore_file_stub.py:573] Could not read datastore data from c:\users\austin\appdata\local\temp\dev_appserver.datastore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 52, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 48, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 503, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 480, in main
    static_caching=static_caching)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3881, in CreateServer
    server = HTTPServerWithScheduler((serve_address, port), handler_class)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3901, in __init__
    request_handler_class)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\SocketServer.py", line 330, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 101, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\SocketServer.py", line 341, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.gaierror: (11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')
2011-02-05 18:32:25 (Process exited with code 1)
```

What can I do to fix this? I have absolutely no experience with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a different port:

1. In the Google App Engine Launcher, click once on your app
2. From the menu select `Edit` | `Application Settings`
3. Change the port number from `8080` to something like `8888`

[image: Screenshot of settings]

If you want to see what's using a particular port, run `netstat -a -b` from an administrative command prompt.

This may also be a related issue: [How to fix socket.gaierror: (11004, 'getaddrinfo failed') error in GAE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180720/how-to-fix-socket-gaierror-11004-getaddrinfo-failed-error-in-gae)

Answer (score 0):

`socket.gaierror` has to do with your network. Are you using a hostname for your machine and is it not getting mapped to 127.0.0.1 ? In the applauncher (It is only Windows feature), do you see any where where you can setup address to run, if so, you can use localhost or IP-directly (like 127.0.0.1). Also ensure that the default port 8080 is not blocked by your firewall or occupied by some other port.

Comment: I'm not using a hostname and a web tool (http://www.canyouseeme.org/) says that my 8080 port is not currently blocked. Could there be something wrong with my router?