# How to fix socket.gaierror: (11004, 'getaddrinfo failed') error in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sockets, aptana

I'm using Aptana and GAE. When I run GAE launcher or run a server in Aptana 3, I get this error... I've downloaded the lastest version of GAE and still doesnt work...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 76, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 72, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 665, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 629, in main
    static_caching=static_caching)
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4818, in CreateServer
    server = HTTPServerWithScheduler((serve_address, port), handler_class)
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4844, in __init__
    request_handler_class)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\SocketServer.py", line 330, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 101, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\SocketServer.py", line 341, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.gaierror: (11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')
Exception exceptions.AttributeError: '_shutdown' in <module 'threading' from 'C:\Python25\lib\threading.pyc'> ignored
2011-05-30 21:57:24 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Comment: FIXED! after days looking for this problem: I just deleted this line "0.0.0.0       localhost " from my hosts file located in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc" thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FIXED! after days looking for this problem: I just deleted this line "0.0.0.0 localhost " from my hosts file located in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc" thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 8):

Had same problem here, I had to add

`127.0.0.1 myhostname`

and

`::1 myhostname`

to /etc/hosts